# localtime_s depends from current system time for Chile, Santiago time zone

Tags: c, windows, localtime

I'm currently working with "localtime_s" function, here is the syntax:

```
errno_t localtime_s (struct tm* _tm, const time_t *time);
```

and I've found a bit strange behavaiour.
This function returns different "tm_isdst" field of "_tm" structure(for the same "time" argument) for different current system time (the time that is set on the Windows Control panel) if we have Chile, Santiago time zone.

Another words, "localtime_s" gives us different DST transition date(for the same year passed in "time") for different system time (DST transition date is the date where "tm_isdst" field value is "False" and previous day "tm_isdst" value is "True", or vice versa).

It's always correct if the year passed with the "time" argument is the same as the year in the system time. But when the year of system time differs from the year in "time" argument, DST transition date based on the "tm_isdst" values returned by "localtime_s" function becomes wrong.

Example:
Santiago, Chile time zone. 2014 year (passed with "time" argument). First DST transition was between 26/27 of April.
If current system time year is also 2014, all is ok - "tm_isdst" is "True" for April 26 and "False" for April 27.
But if system time year is 2018, "tm_isdst" will be "True" for the dates less equal May 10, and only from May 11 it becomes "False". This means "localtime_s" function consider DST transition date as 11 May, which is wrong.

Another example, if system year is 2010, DST transition date (for year 2014 passed with "time" argument) from the "localtime_s" will be 6 April.
So we are getting different DST transition dates for the same year (but for different years set in Windows).

I don't think it's default behaviour because:

1. I tried to google "localtime_s" function and I didn't found any info about dependency from current system time, specially in function description.
2. I tested "localtime_s" for another time zones (like UTC-8 Pacific Time(US & Canada) and UTC+2 Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Talinn, Vilnius) and it works fine with them - DST transition dates don't depend from current system time.
3. I tested the same "localtime_r" function on Linux and it works fine - DST transition dates also don't depend from current system time (for Santiago time zone as well).
4. If we have 2015 year on Windows system time, "lolaltime_s" function considers we don't have DST transition for any year at all ("tm_isdst" is always "True" for any time and any year). It's obviously wrong from my point of view.

System is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standart, x64.

Could some please say what can cause this issue? Is this "localtime_s" function bug?

P.s. Here are attached few examples of DST transition date dependency from system  year:

[DST transition dates, Santiago, 2014 system time year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P2GD.jpg)

[DST transition dates, Santiago, 2018 system time year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QUjx.jpg)

[DST transition dates, Santiago, 2020 system time year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NltuQ.jpg)

P.p.s. Here is a simple example to test (sorry for the missed '#' before include, stackoverflow doesn't want to save my post with this symbols):

```
include <iostream>
include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t t_26_Apr = 1398517200;                   // 26-Apr-2014
    time_t t_27_Apr = 1398517200 + 24 * 3600;       // 27-Apr-2014
    time_t t_10_May = 1398517200 + 14 * 24 * 3600;  // 10-May-2014
    time_t t_11_May = 1398517200 + 15 * 24 * 3600;  // 11-May-2014
    tm tm_26_Apr;
    tm tm_27_Apr;
    tm tm_10_May;
    tm tm_11_May;

    localtime_s(&tm_26_Apr, &t_26_Apr);
    localtime_s(&tm_27_Apr, &t_27_Apr);
    localtime_s(&tm_10_May, &t_10_May);
    localtime_s(&tm_11_May, &t_11_May);

    std::cout << "26-Apr-2014 DST status is:\t" << tm_26_Apr.tm_isdst << std::endl;
    std::cout << "27-Apr-2014 DST status is:\t" << tm_27_Apr.tm_isdst << std::endl;
    std::cout << "10-May-2014 DST status is:\t" << tm_10_May.tm_isdst << std::endl;
    std::cout << "11-May-2014 DST status is:\t" << tm_11_May.tm_isdst << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Real DST transition date in Santiago for 2014 year is at midnight between 26/27 April. But if Windows system time year is 2018, transition date become 10/11 May. I tested this on 2 different OS (Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2) and 2 different machines, and got the same result.

Comment: As far as I know, the Unix-based implementations of these time functions know all the historical rules for when things changed (DST changes, changes for the rules for DST changes, etc.) in prior years.  But the Windows implementation does not -- it always assumes that the current year's rules (whatever they are) applied in all past years.  Is it possible that when you're calling `localtime` you're getting a Windowsy implementation, but when you call `localtime_s` you're getting a Unixy one, or vice versa?

Comment: Unfortunately the time functions in both the C and C++ standards a are bit of a mess. A look at [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) shows that very little is required in terms of past timezone support by the standard unfortunately. I can't speak for POSIX. As for `localtime_s` it seems to have the same lack of constraints. As best I can tell these are compliant, albeit frustrating implementations. It is worth noting that C++ [is trying to fix this situation](http://eel.is/c++draft/time)

Comment: This can only be as accurate as machine maintenance allows.  An example of an update that applies to Santiago is [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3153731/may-2016-dst-update-for-azerbaijan-chile-haiti-and-morocco-in-windows).  There are surely more, I didn't look.  You can double-check with Regedit.exe, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Pacific SA Standard Time\Dynamic DST  On my machine (Win10 client) I see the every year between 2007 and 2016 covered.  Ymmv.

Comment: You haven't shown how you have tested this. It's more likely that there is an error in you code. It's less likely that time functions would be wrong for an entire country.

Comment: I updated the post and added a simple code example. Hope it will help someone to tell more about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed look odd. On Windows 10, I checked the dates for Santiago. Year 2014 and 2016 have different daylight savings dates. Year 2015 has no information at all (maybe no daylight savings for that year) It's not unusual that these dates change over time. For much of US and Canada it also changed in 2007. Daylight saving is a useless concept to begin with, and governments screw with it often for no good reason. Not much you can do about it except rely on the operating system. Use UTC to store time internally if possible, convert to local time for output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    for(int year = 2014; year < 2020; year++)
    {
        TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tz;
        GetTimeZoneInformationForYear((USHORT)year, NULL, &tz);

        printf("Year %d, bias: %d\n", year, tz.Bias);
        printf("Standard: %02d/%02d %02d:%02d\n",
            tz.StandardDate.wMonth, tz.StandardDate.wDay,
            tz.StandardDate.wHour, tz.StandardDate.wMinute);

        printf("Daylight: %02d/%02d %02d:%02d\n\n",
            tz.DaylightDate.wMonth, tz.StandardDate.wDay,
            tz.DaylightDate.wHour, tz.DaylightDate.wMinute);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Year 2014, bias: 240
Standard: 04/05 23:59
Daylight: 09/05 23:59

Year 2015, bias: 180
Standard: 00/00 00:00
Daylight: 00/00 00:00

Year 2016, bias: 240
Standard: 05/02 23:59
Daylight: 08/02 23:59

Year 2017, bias: 240
Standard: 05/02 23:59
Daylight: 08/02 23:59

Year 2018, bias: 240
Standard: 05/02 23:59
Daylight: 08/02 23:59

Year 2019, bias: 240
Standard: 05/02 23:59
Daylight: 08/02 23:59
```